# How to resolve an IncompatibleRemoteServiceException in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I've created a new GWT project through the Eclipse plugin - and just trying to call this server side function. I deleted the initial "greet" function which was created with the generated code - and replaced it with another function "QueryResponse search(QueryRequest query). But then I'm getting this error when the client calls the function. It appears to me as though the generated sample "greet" function is being called from somewhere inside the GWT SDK. Help!

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
[WARN] greetServlet: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Could not locate requested method 'greetServer(com.myproject.shared.QueryRequest)' in interface 'com.myproject.client.GreetingService' )
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:310)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

**EDIT:** Here's and interesting observation I made today. The error does not show when the call is not fired by an event. To be specific, this call was made when a form was submitted. Today I tried removing the form submission part and just make the call when the onmodule load function is called - and it worked fine. The appropriate result was returned from the server. But when, I put it back inside the form submit event, this error shows up. Not just that - this error shows up whenever the form is submitted - whether or not a server call is triggered. If you submit the form once, the error shows up. After the first error, it shows up even when you try to refresh the page.

Comment: Did you rename the method in the `Async` interface as well? Remember that all RPC methods are defined both client and server side.

Comment: Yes I did: Eclipse throws and error if you don't. Here it is:  void search(QueryRequest query, AsyncCallback<QueryResponse> callback);

Comment: Did you (re)start the DevMode *after* making that change? Did you reload your browser *after* making that change? And are you running in DevMode? (have the `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` in your URL)

Comment: Yes I'm running dev mode. Restarted dev mode - that didn't work. Then restarted eclipse - that didn't work either.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit added today at the bottom of the main question.

Comment: Am having a similar issue , so have created a new post [incompatibleremoteserviceexception-after-migrating-to-gwt-2-8-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213482/incompatibleremoteserviceexception-after-migrating-to-gwt-2-8-1)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I eventually fixed it by deleting the contents of WEB-INF\classes as it was caching up some old stuff in there.

Obviously also try clearing down C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp as that is a common GWT problem..

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem than you and I fix it just right now :
If your error don't show up if you don't send your call, it's because the call to the server don't work.
I found that JS on your client side don't refresh properly. try to restart your server then refresh your browser by refreshing the local cached version. if my explanation is too complex : clear cache. On chrome you can use crtl-f5 instead of just f5 and on firefox ctrl-R.

Answer (score 0):

I initialized the GWT project using Maven (https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/). After rebuilding the Maven project the problem is gone. Apparently there were some stale files causing conflicts.