# GWT override exception message

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a problem - When the server encounters any exception it will throw a message to the client which in turn is matched against a preset in the GWT library.

My concern is the message reveal the classes that having exception which i do not wish to let user know about this. Just to tell the user the server is having problem please try again.

I have found the RPC.class is doing the job of returning the message. I also override the class by looking the source code from gwt and put at the same package name folder. In the development mode, it work like a charm, it tell exactly what i want to tell user.

But after i put under production, it seem like back to default like my override class did not work. I have look into the internet and found during the production the server is using gwt-servlet.jar instead of gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jar. I do not know is that any connection with my problem.

Any 1 have face this kind of issue? or any experience of override gwt classes?

Comment: FYI the exception is under "IncompatibleRemoteServiceException".

Comment: "IncompatibleRemoteServiceException" occurs when your client side method signature/call doesn't match with server side signature. For reference you can go through this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334076/how-to-resolve-an-incompatibleremoteserviceexception-in-gwt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334076/how-to-resolve-an-incompatibleremoteserviceexception-in-gwt)